# Given Matrix A over Field K, is this matrix diagonizable, not diagonizable, or it depends on the field K?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given this 3*3-matrix-A:

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}

I did compute the eigenvalues, dimension of eigenspace, and it seems to be diagonizable according to the standard criteria, over the complex numbers, atleast.

But, is that actually enough to tell that A is diagonizable over every possible field K?

For me it does not seem like a conclusive approach to tell, if something is diagonizable over any field K.

Comment: In english we say "field", not "body" [Korper]. The standard criterion for diagonalsability over $K$ is this: $A$ is diagonalizable over $K$ if and only if the minimal polynomial $m_A(X)$ is the product of distinct linear factors in $K[X]$.

Comment: The diagonalisability depends on the underlying field $F$. E.g. when $\operatorname{char}(F)=3$, we have $A^3=0\ne A$. Hence $A$ is a nonzero nilpotent matrix and it is non-diagonalisable. Over a general field $F$, since the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^3+3x$, using the criterion in terms of minimal polynomial mentioned in the comment above, it can be shown that $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if $\operatorname{char}(F)\ne3$ and $-3$ has a square root in $F$.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "body K"? If you mean "field K", the answer is "no." You have to look at each field separately. It may be helpful to observe that a field is either of characteristic 0, in which case it contains a sub-field isomorphic to the rationals or of prime characteristic, which will lead you into some number theory. Please do not use "diagonalizable"as a short form for "diagonalizable by similarity" as I have assumed you are doing. There are many other ways of diagonalizing a matrix. If I thought you meant "diagonalizing by congruence"or "diagonalizing by equivalence" etc., my answer would be very different.